# How do I make a condition that could combine said plans in the program, and add their prices?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am new to Java.
How do I make a condition that could possibly combine the said "plans" in the program and add their prices? For now the program is only set for one plan and price. Which can only output one plan, and price.

Like for example if I input:

Enter number of talk minutes: 125

Enter number of text messages sent: 225

Enter number of gigabytes used: 1.3

The outcome should be like

Recommended Cellular Plans: Plan B and Plan E
Total Bill: $134.00

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;


import java.util.Scanner;


public class HorizonPhones {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number of talk minutes: ");
    int minutes = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter amount of text messages sent: ");
    int texts = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter amount of gigabytes used: ");
    double gigaBytes = scanner.nextDouble();
    double planA = 49.00;
    double planB = 55.00;
    double planC = 61.00;
    double planD = 70.00;
    double planE = 79.00;
    double planF = 87.00;

    if (minutes <= 500 && texts == 0 && gigaBytes == 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Recommended Cellular Plans: Plan A");
            System.out.println("Total Bill: " + planA);
            return;
    }
    if (minutes < 500 && texts > 1 && gigaBytes == 0) {
            System.out.println("Recommended Cellular Plans: Plan B");
            System.out.println("Total Bill: " + planB);
            return;
    }
    if (minutes > 500 && texts <= 100 && gigaBytes == 0) {
            System.out.println("Recommended Cellular Plans: Plan C");
            System.out.println("Total Bill: " + planC);
            return;
    }
    if (minutes > 500 && texts >= 100 && gigaBytes == 0) {
            System.out.println("Recommended Cellular Plans: Plan D");
            System.out.println("Total bill: " + planD);
            return;
    }
    if (minutes > 500 && texts >= 1 && gigaBytes < 2) {
            System.out.println("Recommended Cellular Plans: Plan E");
            System.out.println("Total bill: " + planE);
            return;
    }
    if (minutes > 500 && texts > 1 && gigaBytes > 2) {
            System.out.println("Recommended Cellular Plans: Plan F");
            System.out.println("Total bill: " + planF);
            return;
    }

  }     
}
```

Comment: You can make a Class Plan, with int gigaBytes, int texts and int minutes attributes. Instance all your plans in a List<Plan> plans, stream and filter by needed criterias.

Answer (score 0):

Before you `if(){}` blocks start declare two things one String[] (for storing plan's name) and another `int sum=0;` variable for storing total sum. And remove return from each `if(){}` block. Then in each block just do this.

```
String[] plansName = new String[];
int sum = 0;
if (minutes <= 500 && texts == 0 && gigaBytes == 0 ) {
        plansName.push("planA");
        sum += planA;            
}
...
```

Similarly do for all `if(){}` blocks and at the end print `plansName` and `sum` values.